# How to get multiple images from a filestream in C#

Tags: c#, image, streaming, filestream

I have a `Stream myStream` and I want to get a jpeg from it. This would be ok if the stream was just a jpeg, I would just do `Image img = Image.FromStream(MyStream);` but the stream is actually a header (ASCII text) followed by a jpeg, followed by a header, followed by a jpeg...

I can extract the headers easily, and they contain information about the jpeg (specifically its resolution and size in bytes) but I don't know how to then get the images as they come through and save them to disk (actually I only want to display them one after the other in an animation, but it's kinda the same thing).

Anyone any ideas?

Here's what the stream looks like:

`[320,240,10734]jpegDataIncomprihensibleTextGoingOnForAges[320,240,10032]jpegDataIncomprihensibleTextGoingOnForAges...`

Comment: If you can extract headers, what prevents you to extract images in same way? you know their sizess.

Comment: Did you try using the "size in bytes" value to determine how many bytes to read from the stream for the current image? Then do this as a loop until there is no more data.

Comment: because I extract them by reading until I get to ] but I don't know what the jpeg will end with

Comment: Does it end at the next "["? Is the stream chunked? Can image byte array contain "[" or "]" within the image portion?

Comment: @Tom A No, because I'm not sure how to do that. That's probably the solution I'm looking for if you could add an answer.

Comment: `Stream` has a `Read` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method that accepts offset/count, you can control where to start reading and how many bytes to read. Have you attempted this? Can you post what you did attempt?

Comment: @TomA Too many comments, yes it ends at the next [. I don't know what chunked means but I don't think so. I don't know what the image array looks like really. It might contain a [ or ]

Edit: please make an answer so I can discuss it there, we're adding too many comments and I keep replying out of sync

Edit2: I'd forgotten about stream.Read. I've been programming for too long today.

Comment: The trick is to use `Stream.Read` and supply the number of bytes to read, which you can fetch from your header. Using this and a loop, you should be able to 1) extract header, 2) read next image , 3) go back to 1.. until the stream is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you really don't want to try to do this with a text file. You want to read the file as binary, and that's what [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

So read the first header. That gives you the jpeg size in bytes. Position the file to the start of the jpeg and read that many bytes into memory. Then create a `MemoryStream` and construct the image from that stream.

So, broadly:

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
while not end of file
{
    // read header. Probably want to read characters one at a time here.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = reader.ReadChar();
        sb.Append(c);
    } while c != ']';
    var header = sb.ToString();

    // parse header. One of the fields you get is SizeInBytes

    var imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes(SizeInBytes);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    var jpeg = Image.FromStream(stream);

    // do what you want with the jpeg here.

    // the file should be positioned at the start of the next header
    // so just do it all again until no more data.
}
```

Comment: This looks like the perfect answer. memoryStream was the key to solving this problem. thank you for your help. Also, I think it's `reader.Read(SizeInBytes);` but I might be mistaken. Thank you for the tip about BinaryReader too.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, `reader.ReadBytes(SizeInBytes);` works for BinaryReader which is what you've used, but I'm sure you know that. I shall take my ignorance elsewhere

Comment: @captainjamie: You could also use `reader.Read(imageBytes, 0, SizeInBytes)`, provided you allocated `imageBytes` (an array of byte) ahead of time.